# Print AnchorPane as PNG

Tags: java, javafx, png

I would print as png my anchorpane: I load in my controller an image and write some text, than I want save the entire panel, but I don't know which tools I have to use.

```
URL fxmlpath = this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/ListaNotaSpesa.fxml");

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
AnchorPane pane= loader.load(fxmlpath);


Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

primaryStage.setTitle("Inserisci Note Spese");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Node.snapshot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot%28javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29).

> Takes a snapshot of this node at the next frame and calls the
>   specified callback method when the image is ready. CSS and layout
>   processing will be done for the node, and any of its children, prior
>   to rendering it. The entire destination image is cleared to the fill
>   Paint specified by the SnapshotParameters. This node is then rendered
>   to the image.

Example:

```
WritableImage image = anchorPane.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

File file = new File("D:\\anchor.png");

ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
```

Comment: Ty dude, you save my job